# What is a service name space in get_service_last_accessed_details_with_entities in AWS while integrating with python?

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, pymongo, boto3

In order to get a response from the AWS api which is **get_service_last_accessed_details_with_entities** using python boto3 library, it asks for a required parameter called service_namespace.

The syntax to get the response is as follow:

```
response = client.get_service_last_accessed_details_with_entities(JobId="IhavethejobID",ServiceNamespace='string')
```

Here in the serviceNamespace, what is the value should I have to add in order to get the response?

Comment: I would say it's the service you're using ? ECS, EC2 etc...

Comment: Just give the string like ServiceNamespace='ECS'?@Bernardostearnsreisen

Comment: I would say so, I found this information here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-applicationautoscaling.ServiceNamespace.html ...

Comment: Post this as an answer, I ll accept it. This is correct way.@Bernardostearnsreisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can find in their `AWS Cloud Development Kit` [docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-applicationautoscaling.ServiceNamespace.html). it's the service you're using in AWS. Such as ECS, EC2 and others...

```
enum ServiceNamespace : The service that supports Application AutoScaling.

Members
Name                Description
ECS                 Elastic Container Service.
ELASTIC_MAP_REDUCE  Elastic Map Reduce.
EC2                 Elastic Compute Cloud.
APPSTREAM           App Stream.
DYNAMODB            Dynamo DB.
RDS Relational      Database Service.
SAGEMAKER           SageMaker.
CUSTOM_RESOURCE     Custom Resource.
LAMBDA              Lambda.
COMPREHEND          Comprehend.
```